# Is there any way to simulate the Polarization vs Electric Field loop of BaTiO3 using Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, berry-phase, electric-field, polarizability

I'm new to the Quantum ESPRESSO package. There are articles outlining the procedure of indirectly simulating the P-E loop of piezo-electric materials via Berry phase calculations.One procedure is indicated below:

> "Perform a set of finite field calculations and plot the stress vs applied electric field, then the slope at zero field gives you the piezoelectric coefficients. For a more elegant solution, you can check the following paper: S. de Gironcoli et al. PRL 62, 2853 (1989)"

**But I couldn't find any explicit step-wise procedure for simulating the P-E loop.** So any help regarding the topic will be good.

Comment: Maybe a slight lead on this,  materials project has this property calculated i think for some materials with vasp, should be similar?

Comment: Did you understand Tristan's comment? Perhaps he's talking about this: https://materialsproject.org/ and saying that they did what you want to do, for some materials using VASP. I suppose you just have to do whatever they did in VASP, but instead in Quantum ESPRESSO. Does it seem possible?

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes I have checked out the VASP version but Im not entirely sure as to how Im supposed to implement it on quantum-ESPRESSO. Ive checked out the examples on their gitlab repo (example 10), but the theory of polarization feels alien to me. It might take sometime to find the solution.

Comment: Why don't you post how to do it in VASP and then ask how QE can do it?